# Weird editor of RDLC in Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, rdlc

I have an rdlc (definition is 2010) and trying to edit it in the Visual studio 2017 (community).

When I open it in the designer (which is an separated extension and require to install)

It ask me to update the RDLC to latest version.

I can edit it in visual studio 2017 after update RDLC.

But edited RDLC CANNOT be rendered (the definition updated to 2016)

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition
```

If I choose **not** to update, the report viewer can display the report correctly.

Then I try to search why the reportViewer unable to render definition 2016 RDLC.

I found that the reportViewer version in Visual studio 2017 is version 12.

According to information from web, the latest version of report viewer is 14.

And I found there is actually NO WAY to update the report viewer to 14 (at least in community version).

I am curious why the handling of visual studio 2017 can be that bad

The RDLC **designer** forces us to update the RDLC to 2016 definition in visual studio 2017

But there is no way to update the **viewer** to render the report with 2016 definition

Installed things:
[image]
[image][image]

Designer ask me to update when trying to view the RDLC in the VS2017
[image]

Updated RDLC cannot be rendered in the ReportViewer

If choose not to update, the reportViewer can be displayed, but designer cannot view and edit the RDLC[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different components for RDLC in Visual Studio 2017.

**Designer**

Installed as an extension - you need this to edit your reports. I understand this is what you have already:
[Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) (marketplace.visualstudio.com)

**Projects/Wizards**

A separate extension. Adds the projects and wizards into Visual Studio that you use for creating new projects/reports.

[Microsoft Reporting Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio) (marketplace.visualstudio.com)

*Extension links only for clarification, you can find them in Visual Studio in:

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online.*

**ReportViewerControl**

For each project you have that uses ReportViewer, you need the ReportViewerControl NuGet package to give you the updated viewer:

For **Winforms** (or **WPF** via a [WindowsFormsHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?view=netframework-4.7.2) (learn.microsoft.com)):

[Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/150.900.148) (nuget.org)

For **ASP.Net** (never used personally):

[Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/150.900.148) (nuget.org)

*Again, links only for clarification, you can find in Visual Studio in:

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Browse.*

Note: Be sure to install the correct nuget packages. If you're coming from VS2015 you might previously have had unofficial packages installed. Check the name carefully (and the link if you need to confirm). Screenshot below:

[image]

**Further info**

[Integrating Reporting Services Using the Report Viewer Controls - Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017) (learn.microsoft.com)

Comment: things that you mentioned, are installed already, please check the attached screen capture. the issue is, the designer force me to update the report to 2016 (if i choose not update, the report designer cannot edit the report. If i updated it, it cannot be rendered on the screen (the version 12 reportviewer cannot render a 2016 RDLC

Comment: the dilemma is rather choose not to update the RDLC, so that the reportViewer can display the report (but cannot edit it at VS2017 designer), or update the RDLC, then i can edit the report, but this updated RDLC unable to be rendered in the reportViewer

Comment: You're using the wrong nuget package (an unofficial package of the version 12 ReportViewer - I used the same one in VS2015). Microsoft released official ones when it got moved out of VS2017 which have the updated control. See update in answer - the name is different.

Comment: ok, you found the cause. the freaking nuget in VS2017 are referencing the offline package and i just saw it. sick

Comment: everything is fine after updating the reportViewer to version 15.